# Jenkins Artifactory Plugin ignoring Maven UniqueVersion

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

I am facing an issue with the Jenkins Artifactory plugin. When I deploy to Artifacfory using Maven3 (as uniqueVersion is now by default true) the Jars have a timestamp suffixed to their names. However, while running a custom job for deploying to Artifactory that uses the Artifacory plugin, the plugin is not appending the timestamp. Is there any way I could tell the plugin to stick to the default Maven behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [force the Artifactory repo to use unique snapshots](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Local+Repositories#LocalRepositories-Maven,Gradle,IvyandSBTRepositories), regardless of what Maven sends. In this case Artifactory will add the timestamp even if the file is being uploaded without it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I discovered that Artifactory "Maven Snapshot Version Behavior " setting for this snapshot repo was set at "Deployer" so it honored whatever Jenkins Artifactory plugin sent it. I corrected it by changing to "Unique". However, there certainly is a bug with the Jenkins Artifactory plugin that it doesn't send the UniqueVersion as deployer.